# Java Swing: Generating dynamic GUI forms from XML

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, swing

I am writing this application in Java, where I have a `JTree` on the left of the `JFrame`, and the item selected in the `JTree` determines what appears on the right. This is similar to `Edit --> Preferences` in Thunderbird, and several other applications' preferences.

Anyhow the main difference is that in my app the stuff on the right is dynamic, and needs to be generated at run time using input from a file.

What I am after is various ways in which this can be accomplished, code snippets or existing frameworks / libraries if they exist.

The input file needs to be something higher level than the sort of XML generated during Serialization. No output capability is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [JEasy Framework](http://www.jeasy.de/JEasyquestions.htm) looks to do exactly what you're asking for.

But here's a whole list of similar projects: http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-user-interface-toolkits

There's a short description for each one and a link to their project page. You'll want to look at a handful of the ones that sound good to you, and then try one or two for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As of now i think one of the most actively used is [Swixml](http://www.swixml.org). better support compared to JEasy.

have been using it for some while now, and is very easy to learn too

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it - http://www.soyatec.com/eface/ - XAML/WPF for Java.