# Building a Java Swing application from a configuration file

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Do you know of any tutorial/example on how to code a dynamic GUI with Java Swing in Netbeans? What I'd like to do is:

- Write a text configuration file with parameters for several components
- Launch the GUI, which reads the configuration file and automatically builds the graphical interface for those components.

I've never worked with Java GUI before, so I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: You might wanna learn how GUI works building your own, before dynamically creating them using a config file.

Comment: @Spaffo: *"I've never worked with Java GUI before, so I'm not really sure where to start."*  Start with setting Netbeans aside & figure how to code **static** (i.e. non-dynamic) GUIs.

Comment: Doesnt Android have a feature similar to this? I think it uses XML

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Swing: Generating dynamic GUI forms from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999182/java-swing-generating-dynamic-gui-forms-from-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Everything for creating the GUI can be found there.  You can choose your own configuration file format (XML, JSON), parse it and away you go.  There are probably a number of solutions just like this in open source.

Answer (score 2):

The [*Swing GUI Builder*](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html),  (formerly Project Matisse), creates such configuration files as a normal part of its operation. The files have the extension `.form`.

Comment: I do not think the dot-form files are not used to create the swing object tree at run-time.  I think they are used to generate code that gets compiled by javac.

Comment: @vkraemer: You are correct; I'd hoped `ant` might do, but a trip through the editor seems to be required.

Answer (score 0):

[SwiXml](http://www.swixml.org/) looks like a possible answer for this.

I found this (and the likely dup using this query: http://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+java+swing+gui).