# Create swing component based on property

Tags: java, swing, annotations

I have a small program, which is able to load components during the runtime. I would like to write a small API for those components. The main program should recognize properties from the component and create for each property a swing component. My idea was to use annotations, something like:

```
@Property(name = "X",  PropertyType.Textfield, description = "Value for X")
private int x;
```

What do you think about it? Any problems with that? Are there similar implementations or other options? Thanks for all advices and hints!

**Update**
Please, notice that I'm not able to use third party libraries.

**Update**
I would like to create an abstract class, which is able to create swing components based on the attributes from the concert class. The abstract class controls the presentation. For example (pseudo code):

```
public class A {
    /**
     * Create swing component based on the concret class
     * In this example class A should create a jTextField with a jLable "Cities". So I have not to create each component manuel, 
     * If the text field changed the attribute for cities should set (My idea was with propertyChangesSupport).
     */
}

public class B extends A {
    @Property(name = "Cities",  PropertyType.Textfield, description = "Number of cities")
    private int cities;
}
```

Comment: I've not seen annotations do this, but I have seen XML serialization implementations such as those described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999182/java-swing-generating-dynamic-gui-forms-from-xml).

Comment: But having said that, please understand that I'm no expert in this field. I will await any true good answers with you.

Comment: @hovercraft-full-of-eels Thanks for your reply. I did a lot of research and I also just found the solutions with xml. Is there anything what would be against annotations?

Comment: My knowledge of annotations is somewhat limited. Let's see if any pros can give you some decent information.

Comment: @hofmeister, could you please let us know: what is the use case of doing such. I mean do you want to generate Bean class to a project folder so that they can be reused later. What i mean what are you asking is possible but the way is to use Reflection + writing a class file. So do want to be able to use the class dynamically ?

Comment: @Sage I'm trying to create swing components based on the concert class from the abstract class. That help me to create this components dynamically and automatically, please see my update. The abstract class controls the presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of actually getting the annotations into the layout, you could do something like this:

```
public class A extends JPanel {

A() {
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    addProperties();
}

private void addProperties() {
    for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        Property prop = field.getAnnotation(Property.class);
        if (prop != null) {
            createAndAddComponents(prop);
        }
    }
}

private void createAndAddComponents(Property prop) {
    JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(prop.name());
    this.add(jLabel);
    switch (prop.type()) {
    case Textfield:
        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
        this.add(jTextField);
    case ...
        ...
    }
}
}
```

Of course, that won't look fancy because I'm using `FlowLayout` to avoid clutter in the example. For the value of the `JTextField`, I'm not sure what direction you want to take. You could add `DocumentListener`s that will directly update the related `Field` object or something, but I'm not sure what the requirements are. Here's one idea:

```
jTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    try {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(jTextField.getText());
        field.setInt(A.this, value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
    }
}

......
});
```

And you could also do some PropertyChangeSupport in there when you set the value.

I made a runnable example using GroupLayout and PropertyChangeSupport that actually looks okay...
[image: Example Run]

The code is somewhat messy (particularly my use of GroupLayout, sorry), but here it is in case you need something to look at.. I hope I'm not making this too cluttered...

```
public class B extends A {
    @Property(name = "Cities",  type = PropertyType.Textfield, description = "Number of cities")
    private int cities;
    @Property(name = "Cool Cities",  type = PropertyType.Textfield, description = "Number of cool cities")
    private int coolCities;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.addPropertyChangeListener("cities", new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Cities: " + b.cities);
            }

        });
        b.addPropertyChangeListener("coolCities", new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Cool Cities: " + b.coolCities);
            }

        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(b);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


public class A extends JPanel {

    //Need this retention policy, otherwise the annotations aren't available at runtime:
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Property {
        String name();
        PropertyType type();
        String description();
    }

    public enum PropertyType {
        Textfield
    }


    A() {
        addProperties();
    }

    private void addProperties() {
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        Group column1 = layout.createParallelGroup();
        Group column2 = layout.createParallelGroup();
        Group vertical = layout.createSequentialGroup();

        for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true); // only needed for setting the value.
            Property prop = field.getAnnotation(Property.class);
            if (prop != null) {
                Group row = layout.createParallelGroup();

                createAndAddComponents( prop, column1, column2, row, field );
                vertical.addGroup(row);
            }
        }
        Group horizontal = layout.createSequentialGroup();
        horizontal.addGroup(column1);
        horizontal.addGroup(column2);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(horizontal);
        layout.setVerticalGroup(vertical);
    }

    private void createAndAddComponents(Property prop, Group column1, Group column2, Group vertical, final Field field) {
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(prop.name() + " (" + prop.description() + ")");
        column1.addComponent(jLabel);
        vertical.addComponent(jLabel);
        switch (prop.type()) {
        case Textfield:
            final JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
            jTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    updateValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    updateValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    updateValue();
                }

                private void updateValue() {
                    try {
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(jTextField.getText());
                        field.setInt(A.this, value);
                        firePropertyChange(field.getName(), "figure out old", value);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                    }
                }

            });
            column2.addComponent(jTextField);
            vertical.addComponent(jTextField, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion (I know I shouldn't write opinions but only facts on stackoverflow answers, but here the question is "what do you think about it?"... :-) ) in this solution you are mixing Model and View information in class B (particularly having that PropertyType.Textfield in your annotation). I know MVC pattern is not a law (even Android Adapter breaks MVC contract and it's ok anyway :-) ), but it is generally considered good practice.

If I'm getting you right you have class A that provides the view (swing components) for class B. So A is a view and B is a model. For this reason I wouldn't have B to extend A because it breaks the "IS A" relationship (B extends A means "B is a A" and in your case this would mean B is a view while it is not).

As a different option, did you consider investigating an approach based on JavaBeans and PropertyEditors? it should be more in line with the regular management of "runtime-loaded" components in swing.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/advanced/customization.html

I wrote a simple example just to show you what I mean:

Here is my class B:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class B {
   private int x = 0;
   private Color c = Color.BLUE;
   private Address address;

   public B() {
      address = new Address();
      address.setCity("Liverpool");
      address.setState("England");
      address.setStreet("Penny Lane");
      address.setNumber("1");
      address.setZip("12345");
   }

   public int getX() {
      return x;
   }

   public void setX(int x) {
      this.x = x;
   }

   public Color getC() {
      return c;
   }

   public void setC(Color c) {
      this.c = c;
   }

   public Address getAddress() {
      return address;
   }

   public void setAddress(Address address) {
      this.address = address;
   }
}
```

And this is my test GUI:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test extends JFrame {

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public Test(Object b) {
      super("Test");
      initGUI(b);
   }

   private void initGUI(Object b) {
      Class<?> c = b.getClass();
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

      try {
         BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(c);
         for (PropertyDescriptor pd : info.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            try {
               Method readMethod = pd.getReadMethod();
               Object val = readMethod.invoke(b, new Object[0]);
               // Or you may want to access the field directly... but it has to be not-private
               // Field f = c.getDeclaredField(pd.getName());
               // Object val = f.get(b);
               //
               // You can use annotations to filter... for instance just consider annotated
               // fields/methods and discard the others...
               // if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Property.class)) {
               // ...

               java.beans.PropertyEditor editor = java.beans.PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(val.getClass());
               if (editor != null) {
                  editor.setValue(val);
                  add(new JLabel(pd.getDisplayName()));
                  if (editor.supportsCustomEditor()) {
                     add(editor.getCustomEditor());
                  } else {
                     String[] tags = editor.getTags();
                     if (tags != null) {
                        add(new JComboBox<String>(tags));
                     } else {
                        if (editor.getAsText() != null) {
                           add(new JTextField(editor.getAsText()));
                        }else{
                           add(new JPanel());
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }

            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      } catch (IntrospectionException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      B b = new B();

      Test t = new Test(b);
      t.pack();
      t.setVisible(true);

   }

}
```

PropertyEditorManager provides a default editor for int and for Color. What about my class Address?

```
public class Address {
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private String zip;
   private String street;
   private String number;

   public String getCity() {
      return city;
   }

   public void setCity(String city) {
      this.city = city;
   }

   public String getState() {
      return state;
   }

   public void setState(String state) {
      this.state = state;
   }

   public String getZip() {
      return zip;
   }

   public void setZip(String zip) {
      this.zip = zip;
   }

   public String getStreet() {
      return street;
   }

   public void setStreet(String street) {
      this.street = street;
   }

   public String getNumber() {
      return number;
   }

   public void setNumber(String number) {
      this.number = number;
   }
}
```

I provide a custom editor for class Address (PropertyEditorManager uses different strategies to discover class editors... I used naming convention)
This is my AddressEditor class:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AddressEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
   @Override
   public boolean supportsCustomEditor() {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getCustomEditor() {
      Address value = (Address) getValue();
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      panel.add(new JTextField(value.getStreet()));
      panel.add(new JTextField(value.getNumber()));
      panel.add(new JTextField(value.getCity()));
      panel.add(new JTextField(value.getState()));
      panel.add(new JTextField(value.getZip()));

      return panel;
   }
}
```

This way B (and also Address) are just models and editors are provided to customize the views.

Well... this was just to respond to your question about other options... I hope I didn't go too much out of track... :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I like to collect ideas, to ensuring a better overview of the possible solutions. Where do you use the AddressEditor? How does you find the editor in class B, nowhere AddressEditor is used?

Comment: PropertyEditorManager does the magic... 
see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditorManager.html


<<The PropertyEditorManager uses three techniques for locating an editor for a given type. [...] Second it tries to locate a suitable class by adding "Editor" to the full qualified classname of the given type (e.g. "foo.bah.FozEditor"). [...]>>


This is the reason why I'm suggesting this approach: this is the standard way swing provides to manage this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way in my opinion would be to create something like the following.

Create a plain *data bean* with annotated fields:

```
public class MyBean {

    @Property(name="Cities", PropertyType.Textfield, description = "Number of cities")
    private int cities;

    @Property(name="Countries", PropertyType.Textfield, description = "Number of countries")
    private int countries;

}
```

A class called *FormFactory* which provides the method:

```
public <T> Form<T> createForm(T o);
```

This method creates a Component of the type *Form* by reflecting the fields of the given object and creating a *PropertyComponent* for each field. Simply fill the components into the form by using a GridBagLayout (if you have further questions on this, ask ;).

The generic *Form* class extends the type JPanel and provides the method:

```
public T getBean();
```

A generic *PropertyComponent* is structured like this:

```
public abstract PropertyComponent<T> extends JComponent {
    String propertyName;
    abstract T getValue();
}

public TextfieldStringComponent extends PropertyComponent<String> {
    ...
}
```

The `T getBean()` method of the *Form* class is implemented as follows:

- Create a new empty bean of the type T
- Iterate over each *PropertyComponent*
- Call the `getValue()` method of the field component to retrieve the value
- Fill the value into the bean with the `propertyName` and the retrieved value

Then you can add the created Panel to your UI, and once the data of the form is needed, you get a bean of the type MyBean.

Answer (score 0):

you can absolutely do this. load an object. query its fields with reflection. once you have a field, you can iterate through its annotations. if you find the annotation `@Property`, then get its property type, and ask an object (which you will also have to create), to create the swing component.

i would structure your classes differently though, make pure data classes (class B's), and feed those into some panel that can create the sub components.

Comment: Could you explain "i would structure your classes differently though..." a little bit more?

Comment: you had class `A` create swing components for data class `B`. i dont think its necessary to have the super class do this. in fact it puts an undue burden on the class hierarchy. i would make B not inherit from A, and have A inherit from JPanel. you feed it an instance of B in order to create all the components.

Comment: @tobii did a pretty good job with that, but B inheriting from A, is not strictly necessary